# How can I delete single rows from a class using Parse's cloud PHP library?

Tags: php, arrays, function, api, parse-platform

I am creating a web api for mobile and website . Selecting All data from parse api. i want to delete single row but single row not delete please help me.

My Code:

```
 function deleteBathRow($objectId)
 {

  $query = new ParseQuery("RoomDetail");
  $query->equalTo("objectId", $objectId);
  $question = $query->first();
  if(!empty($question))
  {
    $question->destroy();
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}       
deleteBathRow("39LaGbj");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make cloud code to delete the single row from parse .

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteRoomDetail", function(request, response) {
  var User = Parse.Object.extend("RoomDetail");
   var query =new ParseQuery(User);
   var userID = request.params.roomID;
   query.get(userID,{
    success: function(User) {
    var message = 'success';
    User.destroy({
          useMasterKey: true ,
            success:function() {
            response.success(message);
            return;
            },
            error:function(error) {
            response.error('Could not delete object '+ User.id);
            return;
            }
            });
     },
 error: function(object, error) {
 var message = 'Object could not found';
 response.error(message);
 }
 });
});
```

and call from php code

```
$result = ParseCloud::run("deleteRoomDetail", ["roomID" => "Your roomID"]);
```

Comment: Dear i don't knowledge of java script , i know only php.

Comment: dude as per my knowledge parse cloud code is written in JS only so you cant achieve it with php & also for security purpose cloud code is the best way to deleting the user..

Comment: Sorry dear, I tell you, that  parse written in php please check a website. i am working with PHP parse library link:https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide

Comment: Yes I know that.. I am telling about cloud code . https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#cloud-code please check this in this you will see the cloud code in JS